# How to use the returned boolean value from method (Java)?

Tags: java, android, methods, return, boolean

I'm having trouble using a returned value from a boolean method.

I am testing is a score valid firstly:

```
 public boolean isValidScore() {

    boolean isScoreValid = true;

    scoreHit = Integer.parseInt(scored.getText().toString());//convert the 3 dart score to store it as an integer

    int[] invalidScores = {179, 178, 176, 175, 173, 172, 169, 168, 166, 165, 163, 162};

    boolean invalidNumHit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < invalidScores.length; i++) {
        if (scoreHit == invalidScores[i]) {
            invalidNumHit = true;
        }
    }

    if (scoreHit > 180 || scoreHit > scoreLeft[player] || scoreHit + 1 == scoreLeft[player] || (scoreHit == 159 && scoreLeft[player] == 159) || invalidNumHit) {

        //won't adjust score left if invalid score/checkout entered
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "You've entered an invalid score, Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 75);
        toast.show();

        scored.setText("0");//have to reset score to zero as won't do below as will return from method if invalid score

        isScoreValid = false;//will exit method i.e. won't adjust scores and stats and switch player if invalid score entered.
    }

    return isScoreValid;
}
```

Then I am going into a method which calls this method - I want to then exit from this enterClicked() method if the value is false - here is how I coded this:

```
public void enterClicked(View sender) {

    isValidScore();

    if (isValidScore()) {
    } else {
        return;//exit method if invalid score entered.
    }
       //is more code here.....
}
```

It appears the value for isValidScore() is always true - even when I input an invalid score (I tested it with a toast message).

Comment: `if (isValidScore()) { // do stuff } else{ // don't do stuff}`

Comment: @codeMagic given op's `//is more code here.....` I would make the false condition first. Eg. `if (!isValidScore()) { return; }`

Comment: @Blackbelt  `// is more code here` in `if`, no? Because no code should run in the method if it's not a valid score

Comment: only two people know the answer to your question @codeMagic. One is the op. The other aren't us

Comment: by the way, the fact that `isValidScore()` has side effects is not good. Because it's far from obvious when looking at its name that it has side effects. I'd suggest renaming it, or moving side-effecting code to a separate method (which won't be called from `isValidScore()`)…

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `isValidScore()` twice, and ignoring the result of the first call. You should remove it.

```
public void enterClicked(View sender) {

    isValidScore(); // remove this line

    if (isValidScore()) {
        ...
    } else {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: how would it explain *it appears the value for isValidScore() is always true*

Comment: @Blackbelt It would explain it if OP always had a valid score in even calls and invalid score in odd calls.

Comment: For some reason the isValidScore() method call still doesn't work but at least doing this stopped it getting "true" every time when I tested using Toast (+1 for that).
I can just change the boolean method to void method and create a boolean instance variable called isValidScore and initialize (false if in the if statement) else true if not. However, this is not ideal.  
Does anyone know why isValidScore() call not working properly or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
    if (scoreHit > 180 || scoreHit > scoreLeft[player] || scoreHit + 1 == scoreLeft[player] || (scoreHit == 159 && scoreLeft[player] == 159) || invalidNumHit) {

        //won't adjust score left if invalid score/checkout entered
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "You've entered an invalid score, Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 75);
        toast.show();

        scored.setText("0");//have to reset score to zero as won't do below as will return from method if invalid score

        return false;//will exit method i.e. won't adjust scores and stats and switch player if invalid score entered.
    }
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my suggestion,for the Question that you have raised above.

```
public void enterClicked(View sender) {

        boolean validScore = isValidScore();

        if (validScore == true) {
             //Do Something
        } else {
            return;//exit method if invalid score entered.
        }
          //Default Code to be excuted
    }
```

Comment: tried this - however - tested it and still kept getting true every time for this - thanks for suggestion though + everyone else for efforts and general tips.